# trying to free dynamic allocated memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

So i know this might be asking too much but in my program i used valgrind for some reason it always says that i have 9 allocs mad and 1 free made, but in my code i freed all of the arrays i used, so i dont know are the allocs not being freed.

So if anyone could help me i would appreciate it a lot because im not understanding whats wrong in my code.

Program:

```
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CHARS 1024 /* max characters of a word */
#define MAX_SIZE 5

static int line = 1; /* counts the number of lines of the stdin */
int ident = 0; /*counts the id of jogos*/
static int size_until = 0; /*counts the size of sistema_eq*/
static int size_until2 = 0;/*counts the size of conj_jogos*/

char **sistema_eq;

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char equipas[2][1024];
    int pont[2];
    char nome[MAX_CHARS];
} jogo;

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char nome[MAX_CHARS];
    int vit;
} vitorias;

/*-----------------------------------------*/
jogo *conj_jogos;
vitorias *conj_vit;

void a(char nome_jg[],char team1[],char team2[],int score1,int score2);
void A(char nome[]);

int main()
{
    char c;
    char nome_jg[MAX_CHARS], team1[MAX_CHARS], team2[MAX_CHARS];
    int score1;
    int score2;
    int i;
    conj_jogos = (jogo*)calloc(MAX_SIZE,sizeof(jogo));
    conj_vit = (vitorias*)calloc(MAX_SIZE,sizeof(vitorias));
    sistema_eq = (char**)calloc(MAX_SIZE,sizeof(*sistema_eq));
    for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
    {
        sistema_eq[i] = (char*)calloc(1024,sizeof(char));
    }
    while ((c = getchar())!= 'x') {
    switch (c) 
    {
        case 'A':
        {
            scanf("%1023[^:\n]",nome_jg);
            remove_esp(nome_jg);
            A(nome_jg);
            break;
        }
        case 'a':
        {
            scanf("%1023[^:\n]:%1023[^:\n]:%1023[^:\n]:%d:%d",nome_jg,team1,team2,&score1,&score2);
            remove_esp(nome_jg);
            a(nome_jg,team1,team2,score1,score2);
            line++;
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    free(conj_vit);
    free(conj_jogos);
    for(i=0;i<size_until;i++) free(sistema_eq[i]);
    free(sistema_eq);
   return 0;
}

void A(char nome[])
{
    if (nome_in_sis(nome) == 1)
    {
        printf("%d Equipa existente.\n",line);
        line++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (size_until < MAX_SIZE)
        {
            strcpy(sistema_eq[size_until],nome);
            strcpy(conj_vit[size_until].nome,nome);
            conj_vit[size_until].id = size_until;
            size_until++;
            line++;
        }
        else
        {
            conj_vit = realloc(conj_vit,sizeof(vitorias)*(size_until+1));
            sistema_eq = realloc(sistema_eq,sizeof(char*)*(size_until+1));
            sistema_eq[size_until] = calloc(1024,sizeof(char*));
            strcpy(sistema_eq[size_until],nome);
            strcpy(conj_vit[size_until].nome,nome);
            conj_vit[size_until].id = size_until;
            size_until++;
            line++;

        }
    }
}

void a(char nome_jg[],char team1[],char team2[],int score1,int score2)
{
    int vit;
    if (jogo_in(nome_jg) == 1)
    {
        printf("%d Jogo existente.\n",line);
        line++;
    }
    else if ((nome_in_sis(team1) == 0) || (nome_in_sis(team2) == 0))
        {
        printf("%d Equipa inexistente.\n",line);
        line++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (size_until2 < MAX_SIZE)
        {
            conj_jogos[size_until2] = cria_jogo(nome_jg,team1,team2,score1,score2);
            if (score1 > score2)
            {
                vit = procura_vit(team1);
                conj_vit[vit].vit++;
            }
            else
            {
                vit = procura_vit(team2);
                conj_vit[vit].vit++;  
            }
            size_until2++;
        }
        else
        {
            size_until2++;
            conj_jogos = realloc(conj_jogos,sizeof(jogo)*(size_until2+1));
            conj_jogos[size_until2] = cria_jogo(nome_jg,team1,team2,score1,score2);
            if (score1 > score2)
            {
                vit = procura_vit(team1);
                conj_vit[vit].vit++;
            }
            else
            {
                vit = procura_vit(team2);
                conj_vit[vit].vit++;  
            }
            size_until2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 500 lines of code? Seriously? Please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: Ive shorten it a lot so i dont know, if its still long just ignore my question then

Comment: casting malloc/calloc is almost always wrong.  What is `size_until`?  You allocate `MAX_SIZE`, but free a variable.  Not a good idea.  `conj_jogos[size_until2]` - any chance this goes past `MAX_SIZE`?  If so, bad UB.  Those are the 2 things I see that could cause issues with freeing.

Comment: In this case I would actually advice against shortening the code, because as it is you've shortened it so much that it no longer compiles because of missing functions. One potential issue I see is that you're allocating `sistema_eq` using `MAX_SIZE` as a limiter but freeing using `size_until`. Also, please post the exact output you get from Valgrind.

Comment: actually ur right im allocating all of those arrays with a limiter and then i realloc them because i need more space

Comment: ok i just resolved the issue, but thanks for the help the problem was that i was freeing sistema_eq until size_until which was smaller than MAX_SIZE, causing problems freeing the allocated memory, meaning that was remaining memory to be freed